The forgetful functor $A\downarrow G\to D$ preserves monics?
We are proving the Special Adjoint Functor Theorem in the class:

Let $C$, $D$ be locally small with $D$ further being complete, well-powered and having a coseparating set of objects. Then any continuous $G\colon D\to C$ is a right adjoint.

One of the steps in the presented proof reads:

For any object $A$ of $C$, the comma category $A\downarrow G$ is well-powered since subobjects of $(B, f)$ are certain subobjects of $B$.

However, I am not able to see how the monicity in $A\downarrow G$ implies that in $D$. If $g\colon (B_1, f_1)\to (B, f)$ is monic, then we want that $g\colon B_1\to B$ be monic as well (isn't it?). So, let's start with $h_1, h_2\colon B'\to B_1$ such that $gh_1 = gh_2$. We want that $h_1 = h_2$. We'd be done, by monotonicity of $g$ in $A\downarrow G$, if we can somehow produce a morphism $f'\colon A\to GB'$ such that $f_1 = (Gh_i) f'$ for $i = 1, 2$. But I don't see any way how...

Can someone help?

Incidentally, the same step is used in the nLab entry on SAFT.

What is your definition of $A \downarrow G$? Are you sure that $A$ belongs to the category $C$?

@MartinBrandenburg My bad, I meant $G\colon D\to C$ and not the other way round. Fixed.

The category $A \downarrow G$ has limits and the forgetful functor to $D$ preserves them. This is easy to see using that $G$ preserves limits. Notice that this step is proven in the proof of the General Adjoint Functor Theorem.
Any functor preserving limits also preservers monomorphisms. This is because $f:X \to Y$ is a monomorphism if and only if
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
X & \rightarrow & X \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
X & \rightarrow & Y
\end{array}$$
is a pullback square, where $X \to X$ is the identity.

Two of the $Y$s (the ones in the top-right and bottom-left corners) should be $X$s instead. Also, the identity is $X \to X$, not $Y \to Y$.

Fixed. $~~~~~~~~$
